# Microsoft Excel 2007 function required to find specific information in a worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel worksheet in which I have 15 columns. In column 13 I have 3 names and blank spaces spasmodically placed, in the 3rd column i have dates running from latest to earliest down the page. I want to find a specific name in column 13 and fill a cell on another worksheet with the date from column 3. Can anyone give me a formulae to do this?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can use `VLOOKUP` but the look-up column needs to be left of the column containing the data to write out. To use VLOOKUP we could copy column 3 to column 16.

```
=VLOOKUP('lookup_value', 'table_array', 'col_index_num', 'range_loopup')
=VLOOKUP(A2,DATA_SHEET!$M$2:$P$7,4,FALSE)
```

`'range_loopup'` should be set to FALSE to get exact matches and `'col_index_num'` is the column number of the data to write out (the lookup column is defined as column 1, here). Column `M` is the 13th column of the sheet and column `P` the 16th of the sheet. The column from which data should be shown has to be within the rang of `table_array`.

## Example

Example data (not appropriate columns):

[image]

The sheet in which we want to use the data is shown:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to Thank you for that Daniel, but I neglected to mention that I can not change the positions of the columns without causing a lot of other issues. Any other ideas would be appreciated though